# Angular 2 TypeScript how to get element in Array

Tags: arrays, typescript

I need get element in a array by key.

```
const legendColors = {'On Hold': '#ef2e2e', 'Shipped': '#ff8e28', 'Complete': '#61c673', 'New': '#007cbb'};
```

...

```
return {name: v.name, value: v.value, color: legendColors[v.name]};
```

lint tool return this error on `legendColors[v.name]`:

```
ERROR in src/app/pages/orders/orders.composant.ts(46,62): error TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{ 'On Hold': string; 'Shipped': string; 'Complete': string; 'New': string; }' has no index signature.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript complains because there is no guarantee that `v.name` is one of the keys of `legendColors`, and there is no index signature. You can get past this by giving typescript a hint that `v.name` is in fact one of the keys:

```
return {name: v.name, value: v.value, color: legendColors[v.name as keyof typeof legendColors]};
```

or if legendColors adheres to an interface you already know the name of, you can simplify that a little:

```
return {name: v.name, value: v.value, color: legendColors[v.name as keyof SomeInterface]};
```

Finally, if you're actually not sure if `v.name` is a key of legendColors, then you'll actually have to add an index signature to it.

```
const legendColors: {[key: string]: string} = {'On Hold': '#ef2e2e', 'Shipped': '#ff8e28', 'Complete': '#61c673', 'New': '#007cbb'};
```